# Produce context data for first and last occurrences of every value of an element

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given the following xml:

```
<container>
    <val>2</val>
    <id>1</id>
</container>
<container>
    <val>2</val>
    <id>2</id>
</container>
<container>
    <val>2</val>
    <id>3</id>
</container>
<container>
    <val>4</val>
    <id>1</id>
</container>
<container>
    <val>4</val>
    <id>2</id>
</container>
<container>
    <val>4</val>
    <id>3</id>
</container>
```

I'd like to return something like

```
2 - 1
2 - 3
4 - 1
4 - 3
```

Using a nodeset I've been able to get the last occurrence via:

```
exsl:node-set($list)/container[not(val = following::val)]
```

but I can't figure out how to get the first one.

Comment: Are you interested in grouping by <val>, or just the first and the last <container> in the document?

Comment: @steve: You have to ask what you mean. We're programmers, not psychics.

Comment: Still not clear. Why 2-1 and 2-3, but not 2-2 ??  -1 from me. Such questions are waste of time not only for you, but also for manny people, willing to help and straining their clairvoyant capabilities to the max.  Please, reformulate clearly -- best ask a new question.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: Not 2-2, because it is neither the first nor the last <container> in "//container[val = 2]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first and the last occurrence (document order) in each "`<val>`" group, you can use an `<xsl:key>` like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="ContainerGroupByVal" match="container" use="val" />

  <xsl:variable name="ContainerGroupFirstLast" select="//container[
    generate-id() = generate-id(key('ContainerGroupByVal', val)[1])
    or
    generate-id() = generate-id(key('ContainerGroupByVal', val)[last()])
  ]" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$ContainerGroupFirstLast">
      <xsl:value-of select="val" />
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="id" />
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" /><!-- LF -->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

EDIT #1: A bit of an explanation since this might not be obvious right away:

- The `<xsl:key>` returns all `<container>` nodes having a given `<val>`. You use the `key()` function to query it.
- The `<xsl:variable>` is where it all happens. It reads as:

  - for each of the `<container>` nodes in the document ("`//container`") check…
  - …if it has the same unique id (`generate-id()`) as the first node returned by `key()` or the last node returned by `key()`
  - where `key('ContainerGroupByVal', val)` returns the set of `<container>` nodes matching the current `<val>`
  - if the unique ids match, include the node in the selection
- the `<xsl:for-each>` does the output. It could just as well be a `<xsl:apply-templates>`.

---

EDIT #2: As Dimitre Novatchev rightfully points out in the comments, you should be wary of using the "`//`" XPath shorthand. If you can avoid it, by all means, do so — partly because it potentially selects nodes you don't want, and mainly because it is slower than a more specific XPath expression. For example, if your document looks like:

```
<containers>
  <container><!-- ... --></container>
  <container><!-- ... --></container>
  <container><!-- ... --></container>
</containers>
```

then you should use "`/containers/container`" or "`/*/container`" instead of "`//container`".

---

EDIT #3: An alternative syntax of the above would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="ContainerGroupByVal" match="container" use="val" />

  <xsl:variable name="ContainerGroupFirstLast" select="//container[
    count(
        .
      | key('ContainerGroupByVal', val)[1]
      | key('ContainerGroupByVal', val)[last()]
    ) = 2
  ]" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$ContainerGroupFirstLast">
      <xsl:value-of select="val" />
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="id" />
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" /><!-- LF -->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation: The XPath union operator "`|`" combines it's arguments into a node-set. By definition, a node-set cannot contain duplicate nodes — for example: "`. | . | .`" will create a node-set containing exactly one node (the current node).

This means, if we create a union node-set from the current node ("."), the "`key(…)[1]`" node and the "`key(…)[last()]`" node, it's node count will be 2 if (and only if) the current node equals one of the two other nodes, in all other cases the count will be 3.

Comment: Now it's my turn to +1 you, Tomalak.

Comment: +1 for the solution and guessing capabilities. I only understood what the OP wanted when reading his last comment to weblog's answer.  However... Please, make it at least well-formed, if not complete. Also, why the "//" ? Very bad example for novices.

Comment: I know, but my psychic powers don't reach that far. ;-) I wanted something that at least works when it is tried out. I'll add a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Basic [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp):

```
//container[position() = 1]  <- this is the first one
//container[position() = last()]  <- this is the last one
```

Here's a set of [XPath functions](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_functions.asp) in more detail.

Comment: +1, beat me to it :) Convenience: "//container[1]" and "//container[last()]"

Comment: I'm trying to find the start and end ids for all vals. The first occurrence of a given val might not be container[1]. The example xml I provided is a slimmed down version of my actual xml.

Comment: That shorthand is nice and all, but I think `position() =` is clearer for people who are new to XPath and XSL.

Comment: @Welbog: I just wanted to mention it. No implications made. :)

Answer (score 1):

***I. XSLT 1.0***

**Basically the same solution as the one by Tomalak, but more understandable** *Also it is complete, so you only need to copy and paste the XML document and the transformation and then just press the "Transform" button of your favourite XSLT IDE*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:key name="kContByVal" match="container"
     use="val"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each select=
       "container[generate-id()
                 =
                  generate-id(key('kContByVal',val)[1])
                 ]
       ">

       <xsl:variable name="vthisvalGroup"
        select="key('kContByVal', val)"/>

       <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat($vthisvalGroup[1]/val,
              '-',
              $vthisvalGroup[1]/id,
              '&#xA;'
              )
      "/>
       <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat($vthisvalGroup[last()]/val,
              '-',
              $vthisvalGroup[last()]/id,
              '&#xA;'
              )
        "/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when this transformation is applied on the originally-provided XML document (edited to be well-formed):

```
<t>
    <container>
        <val>2</val>
        <id>1</id>
    </container>
    <container>
        <val>2</val>
        <id>2</id>
    </container>
    <container>
        <val>2</val>
        <id>3</id>
    </container>
    <container>
        <val>4</val>
        <id>1</id>
    </container>
    <container>
        <val>4</val>
        <id>2</id>
    </container>
    <container>
        <val>4</val>
        <id>3</id>
    </container>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
2-1
2-3
4-1
4-3
```

**Do note**:

1. **We use the Muenchian method for grouping** to find one `container` element for each set of such elements that have the same value for `val`.
2. **From the whole node-list of `container` elements with the same `val` value**, we output the required data for the first `container` element in the group and for the last `container` element in the group.

***II. XSLT 2.0***

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="container"
           group-by="val">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[1], current-group()[last()]">
          <xsl:value-of select=
           "concat(val, '-', id, '&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document as above, prodices the wanted result**:

```
2-1
2-3
4-1
4-3
```

**Do note**:

1. The use of the `<xsl:for-each-group>` XSLT instruction.
2. The use of the `current-group()` function.

Comment: +1 from me. I suspect your XSLT 1.0 solution is a little bit more efficient than mine. At least mine is shorter. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks, I just wanted the solution to be understandable. In this respect the XSLT 2.0 solution helps, because it shows in more understandable form the same steps that are in the XSLT 1.0 solution. I think we are doing a good job by making comments on our solutions which then are taken into account and result in even more improved solutions.